# sdbm hash on multiple bytes simultaneously

Tags: c++, hash

This is the code for sdbm hash algorithm that works on byte strings...

```
unsigned long sdbm(unsigned char *key, int bytes)
{
    unsigned long hash = 0;
    unsigned char *end = key + bytes;
    while (key < end) hash = (unsigned long)(*key++) + (hash << 6) + (hash << 16) - hash;
    return hash;
}
```

Suppose now that all of the strings passed to sdbm() were 4 bytes. Is there any way to calculate the sdbm hash of all four bytes at once, treating the string as a 32-bit unsigned value instead? I have this code, assuming that the string keys are all 4 bytes

```
#define SUBHASH(x) ((x << 6) + (x << 16) - x)
unsigned long sdbm4(unsigned long key)
{
    unsigned long hash = (key & 0xFF);
    hash = ((key & 0xFF00) >> 8) + SUBHASH(hash);
    hash = ((key & 0xFF0000) >> 16) + SUBHASH(hash);
    return  (key >> 24) + SUBHASH(hash);
}

char *tmp = "test";

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long a = sdbm((unsigned char *)tmp, 4);
    unsigned long b = sdbm4(*(unsigned long *)tmp);

    printf("a = %lu, b = %lu\n", a, b);

    while (!_kbhit());
    return 0;
}
```

Running this will reveal that both functions calculate the same value, and sdbm4() is specialized to handle a 4 byte string. There is no looping, no testing, and the value on the stack is initialized to the first value immediately. HOWEVER, it would be nice if there were a way to condense this into one statement instead of four. Is that possible? I figured SIMD could probably do it, but I'm not sure how, or if there would be any benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can obviously be *done*,  you just have to expand the statement inline four times.  Your definition of SUBHASH will break if it is passed an expression, so we will have to fix it - so we might as well make it an inline function.

```
inline constexpr unsigned long SubHash(unsigned long x) {
    return ((x << 6) + (x << 16) - x);
}


inline constexpr unsigned long sdbm4(unsigned long key)
{
    return  (key >> 24) + 
                SubHash(((key & 0xFF0000) >> 16) + 
                    SubHash(((key & 0xFF00) >> 8) + 
                        SubHash(key & 0xFF))));
}
```

I would be very surprised if it was worth it though.  The rule is always to write the code for clarity first, and only if profiling shows there is a problem start to optimize.  (Note that one's instinct as to where the bottlenecks are likely to be is almost always wrong.)

If you *really* want to use a #define, you need to change it to:

```
#define SUBHASH(x) (((x) << 6) + ((x) << 16) - (x))
```

You may well find the generated code is identical though.

Comment: I'm trying to squeeze as few statements as possible out of a CGI executable to reduce the load on a local web server. The CPUs may vary between older Intel platforms that may not be as efficient as modern CPUs. I think your code is a slight improvement over mine, and I appreciate the notes. However, I'm still interested in solving the entire hash in one *operation* on a 32-bit long, instead of four operations spread out into one statement. This may not be possible but I figured I'd give it a shot.

Comment: 1.  I am surprised if this function is the bottleneck (but I am, like most programmers, lousy at predicting bottlenecks).  2.  What do you mean by "one operation"?  One instruction? - Won't happen.  If not, what you really care about is the number of CPU cycles - and the only way to know that really is to measure.

Comment: Well, I know I'm not supposed to say "thanks" (it's against the rules)... but thanks for the guidance :)